# How to run NET 6 Service in AWS?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services

A potential customer has a working RDS PostgreSQL database and legacy WinForms client applications. All work fine. But now they want to re-make the system. The idea is: new Client-> new AWS based service ()->existing RDS I suggested to develop the service as NET 6 Core Service. My question: How can I publish the service to AWS? Can it work with the existing RDS?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you want the service to do?

Comment: I want to create a NET Service (REST API) to work with AWS RDS PGSQL database. The other developers can create a clients. And the question is how to publish this  service to AWS? My be I need to create a hybrid Lambda  NET svc?

Comment: okay, you have 3 directions to host the REST API (Serverless, Containers, and EC2). From your comment below on smac2020's answer and also for simplicity you can begin with Serverless direction. In CLI, after installing Lambda tools, run the following command "dotnet new -i Amazon.Lambda.Templates" to get the latest .net lambda projects templates. Then create a new Lambda ASP.NET Core Minimal Api to follow along with the example from AWS Code Library.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are looking for this use case:

**Client app -> .NET backend (AWS SDK for .NET) - > AWS RDS**

If you look in the [AWS Code Library](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/what-is-code-library.html), you will find a very similiar use case. The only difference is in this use case, we use an Aurora Serverless database. But you will get the idea.

This example shows how to use the **AWS SDK for .NET** to create a web application that tracks work items in an Amazon Aurora database and emails reports by using Amazon Simple Email Service (Amazon SES). This example uses a front end built with React.js to interact with a RESTful .NET backend.

1. Integrate a React web application with AWS services.
2. List, add, update, and delete items in an Aurora table.
3. Send an email report of filtered work items using Amazon SES.
4. Deploy and manage example resources with the included AWS CloudFormation script.

[Create an Aurora Serverless work item tracker](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/aurora_example_cross_RDSDataTracker_section.html)

Comment: Thank you @smac2020 , am I right: in this example: the service is deployed as Lamda and the client is located on a local machine?

Comment: "The .NET application is intended to be used with the Item Tracker web client. Follow the instructions in the README to set up and run this client."

this is the link to the intended client (ReactJs) 
https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/resources/clients/react/elwing

The service in the example is not ready to be deployed as Lambda. Check my comment on your post to have the necessary files to deploy as Lambda.